# Windows forms Text Changed on leave event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

Maybe I'm just an idiot, but I can't seem to find an event that will fire for a textbox at the same time as the leave, but only when the contents of the textbox has changed.  Kinda like a combination of textchanged and leave.  I can't use textchanged cause it fires on each keystroke.  Right now I'm storing the current value of the textbox in a variable and comparing it on the leave event, but it seems really hackish.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create your own (derived) class which overrides OnEnter, OnLeave and OnTextChanged to set flags and trigger "your" event.

Something like this:

```
    public class TextBox: System.Windows.Forms.TextBox {
        public event EventHandler LeaveWithChangedText;

        private bool textChanged;

        protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e) {
            textChanged = false;
            base.OnEnter(e);
        }

        protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e) {
            base.OnLeave(e);
            if (textChanged) {
                OnLeaveWithChangedText(e);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnLeaveWithChangedText(EventArgs e) {
            if (LeaveWithChangedText != null) {
                LeaveWithChangedText(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e) {
            textChanged = true;
            base.OnTextChanged(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's probably a better approach than what I'm doing.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious...

Comment: Wow... that's impressive.. I didn't consider overriding both events... damn good idea..

Comment: This solution does not cover one case: When the user edits the text, but finally enters the same text as already in the textbox, the event will still fire. You would need to compare the content at the time leaving the textbox to the content at the time entering the textbox to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @Lucero does it's job almost perfectly.
However, it does not handle the case when a user edits the text and finally enters the same value as before. Therefore I created a similar solution for my own (in C++/CLI, but you can easily adapt it to C#):

```
public ref class EventArgsCTextBox1 : EventArgs
{
public:
  String^ PreviousText;
};

public ref class CTextBox1 : Windows::Forms::TextBox
{
public:
  virtual void OnEnter (EventArgs^ i_oEventArgs) override;
  virtual void OnLeave (EventArgs^ i_oEventArgs) override;

  delegate void EventHandlerCTextBox1 (Object^ i_oSender, EventArgsCTextBox1^ i_oEventArgs);
  event EventHandlerCTextBox1^ LeaveChanged;

private:
  String^ m_sValue;
};

void CTextBox1::OnEnter (System::EventArgs^ i_oEventArgs)
{
  TextBox::OnEnter (i_oEventArgs);
  m_sValue = this->Text;
}

void CTextBox1::OnLeave (System::EventArgs^ i_oEventArgs)
{
  TextBox::OnLeave (i_oEventArgs);
  if (m_sValue != this->Text)
  {
    EventArgsCTextBox1^ oEventArgs = gcnew EventArgsCTextBox1;
    oEventArgs->PreviousText = m_sValue;
    LeaveChanged (this, oEventArgs);
  }
}
```

Comment: Spiffy.... Now, if i could just remember what project I needed this for /: ( 6 years ago, my memory gets fuzzy )

Comment: I also didn't really expect that you change your code now. ;-)

Comment: Well, I /did/ remember it being an issue, but I have no idea what project it was.  I might have even implemented this, but usually I'm good about re-updating my answer with the details.   Thanks for this regardless.